# Is every "almost" isomorphism an isomorphism?

Tags: category-theory, terminology

Let $f:A \mapsto B$, $g:B \mapsto A$ and $h:B \mapsto B$ be such that $g \circ f=\operatorname{id}_A$ and $f \circ g \circ h=\operatorname{id}_B=h \circ f \circ g$. Can we conclude $h=\operatorname{id}_B$? <s>Are there any "naturally occurring" categories where this is false?</s>

We certainly have that $f$ and $g$ are bimorphisms (i.e. simultaneously monomorphisms and epimorphisms), and that $h$ is an automorphism of $B$ (with $h^{-1}=f \circ g$).

In a balanced category such as $\mathbf{Set}$, every bimorphism would be an isomorphism, hence $f$ would have an inverse $f^{-1}$, and we could conclude $f^{-1}=g$ from $g \circ f=\operatorname{id}_A$, which would show $h=\operatorname{id}_B$.

<s>The simplest way to construct a category where $h\neq\operatorname{id}_B$ seems to be to take $\operatorname{hom}(A,A)=\{\operatorname{id}_A\}$, $\operatorname{hom}(B,B)=\{\operatorname{id}_B,h\}$, $\operatorname{hom}(B,A)=\{g\}$ and $\operatorname{hom}(A,B)=\{f,h \circ f\}$. So there are categories where $h=\operatorname{id}_B$ is false.  What about a counterexample for the case $A=B$?</s> **Edit:** Constructing a counterexample without first generating the set of all "valid" relations between $f$, $g$ and $h$ is difficult, because consequences/violations of associativity can easily be overlooked. But if we know the set of all "valid" relations, then we already know the answer.

I have the impression that none of the standard examples of non-[balanced categories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/balanced+category) like posets, quivers, category of rings, or topological categories could provide an example where $h=\operatorname{id}_B$ is false. Is there a name for such an "almost" isomorphism between $A$ and $B$ as provided by $f$, $g$ and $h$<s>, as well as a name for the categories where such "almost" isomorphism are always a real isomorphism</s>?

Comment: A category with one object is a monoid. Consider the free monoid generated by letters f, g and h subject to the relations generated by gf=1 and fgh=1=hfg. Is h equal to 1?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Even the relations $gf=1$ and $fgh=1$ seem sufficient to show $h=1$, if I follow the proof from your answer: $gh=1gh=gfgh=g1=g$, so $fg=fgh=1$ and $1=fgh=1h=h$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that $gh=1gh=gfgh=g1=g$, so that $fg=fgh=1$. It follows that $f$ and $g$ are inverse isomorphisms.

The relation $hfg=1$ has not been used here, so it can be omitted.

Comment: Notice that in your example, the composition $f\circ g$ has to be a morphism $A\to A$ and you decided that $\hom(A,A)$ only contains the identity.